# PdfLatex and UTF-16LE

Tags: pdftex, input-encodings

Is there an option to process UTF-16LE file directly by pdflatex, without the conversion to UTF-8? And does xelatex have such an option?

Answer (score 2):

No.  You should convert to UTF-8.  It’s the easiest solution by far.

The available input encodings for PDFTeX are documented in the `inputenc` manual.  You can also use these encodings, through `luainputenc`, with LuaLaTeX or (despite the name) XeLaTeX.